# How to find a color in a string that contains part of another color

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find a color in a string that contains part of another color.
i.e. Some string will contain Rose Gold and others will contain just Gold or
sometimes the string will contain Black and other times Jet Black or Midnight Black.
and when I use the CONTAINS keyword it works randomly.

```
Galaxy S8 64GB artic Silver                      Just get Silver
Galaxy S7 edge in Black Onyx 32GB (CPO)          Just get Black
Galaxy S7 edge in Silver Titanium 32GB (CPO)     Just gets Silver
Galaxy S7 edge in Blue Coral 32GB                Just gets Blue
Moto Z2 Play - Fine Gold                         Just gets Gold
iPad Mini 4 32GB in Space Gray                   I got Space Gray oddly enough
iPad Pro (9.7) 32GB in Rose Gold                 I got Rose Gold oddly enough
Galaxy Note 8 in Midnight Black                  I got Midnight Black oddly enough


 sProductDescription = Row["ProductDescription"].ToString().Trim().Replace("  ", " ");
 Products pa = db.Products.Single(p => p.ModelNumber == sModelNumber);
 foreach (string x in SharedFunctions.GetColors())
 {
   if (sProductDescription.ToUpper().Contains(x.ToUpper()))
   {
       pa.Color = x;
   }
 }

public static List<string> GetColors()
{
    List<string> lColors = new List<string>(); 
    lColors.Add("Artic Silver");
    lColors.Add("Black Leather");
    lColors.Add("Black Onyx");
    lColors.Add("Black Sapphire");
    lColors.Add("Black Slate");
    lColors.Add("Black");
    lColors.Add("Blue Coral");
    lColors.Add("Blue");
    lColors.Add("Carbon");
    lColors.Add("Fine Gold");
    lColors.Add("Gold Platinum");
    lColors.Add("Gold");
    lColors.Add("Gray");
    lColors.Add("Green");
    lColors.Add("Grey");
    lColors.Add("Jet Black");
    lColors.Add("Lunar Grey");
    lColors.Add("Midnight Black");
    lColors.Add("Orchid Gray");
    lColors.Add("Pearl");
    lColors.Add("Pink");
    lColors.Add("Platinum");
    lColors.Add("Rose Gold");
    lColors.Add("Silver Titanium");
    lColors.Add("Silver");
    lColors.Add("Slate");
    lColors.Add("Space Gray");
    lColors.Add("Sugar White");
    lColors.Add("Titan");
    lColors.Add("White");
    lColors.Add("Yellow");

    return lColors;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean saying `when I use the CONTAINS keyword it works randomly`?

Comment: Please add you code. I think that `CONTAINS` is not working randomly.

Comment: Post the code you have tried which will help others to analyze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make 2 word lists containing the colours; A basic and advanced list. Your first should contain words such as "Rose Gold" and "Titanium White" for example - essentially just all of the colours you intend to use that have 'names'. In your second list, put words that are just plain colours such as "Gold", "Green" or "Silver". Have the program first iterate through your complex colour names, and then your simple one if no match was found in the first one.

```
var complexList = ColourLists.ComplexList;
var simpleList  = ColourLists.SimpleList;
var productName = "iPad Pro(9.7) 32GB in Rose Gold";
var productColour = string.Empty;

foreach(var colour in complexList)
{
    if(productName.Contains(colour, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        productColour = colour;
        break;
    }
}

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(productColour))
{
    foreach (var colour in simpleList)
    {
        if (productName.Contains(colour, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            productColour = colour;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This would return your complex colour (in this scenario, Rose Gold would be found in the first foreach loop). If no complex colour was found, then it would return a simple colour (assuming there is one). You can set your `productName` variable to pull it directly from a model or object instead of being a string like how I've done it.

Comment: You also need to set a boolean to true is found and then say if the not boolean is true the change value.

Comment: You don't. If the colour is found in the first loop, it sets the `productColour` string to the colour it found and breaks out of the loop. If the first loop completes and it found a colour, it will not enter the second loop because the `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(productColour))` will return false - there is already a colour. If there was no colour found, it will enter the if statement and iterate through the second loop. If no colour was found in either, you can handle that later. I'd personally just use objects for this, but that doesn't answer his question :)